# Way to atomically remove from depot file that is already opened for edit in Perforce

Tags: perforce

Right now I am working on Perforce API integration and there is a question I have not found a correct (from my point of view) answer for. If I have opened a file for edit in a changelist how to mark it for delete without reverting it from the changelist?

Right now I am checking the file if it is not read-only or opened for editing in the changelist. In case it is I firstly revert it and then mark it for delete. I have some concerns with this approach because another user can lock the file between those two calls (revert from the changelist and mark for delete). So there is a question if there is any way to do this in one command.

Comment: Nope, there isn't.  Practically speaking, though, there's almost no way another user is going to be able to sneak in and open *and* lock the file in between your own `p4 revert` and `p4 lock`.  If that entirely theoretical problem is the biggest problem in your integration, it will be the best Perforce integration in the world by several orders of magnitude.  :)

Comment: @Samwise, thx for your answer. Yeah, right now it is the biggest problem in our integration process because everything other is working perfectly well (at least for now, and at least how we expected) and I am summarizing critical points of the final solution and started thinking over this problem.

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing what exactly your integration is doing where this is an issue.  If you really have a bunch of automated processes that are contending that vigorously for locks on depot files, your integration likely has more fundamental problems that'll show up in production (i.e. it's not going to scale at all due to the file-level db locks on the server; if your integration is issuing that many commands concurrently it's basically going to DDoS the server).

Comment: @Samwise I cannot tell a lot due to NDA. This is a game engine and we have plenty a lot of users in the single depot and a lot of them work over a single file. We have plenty of experience with other VCS and there was a similar problem (with race conditions over locks) that has actually happened and that is the second part of my motivation for this question. I am glad of receiving your answer to my question. Moreover, I was very interested in answer to it due to my personal leaning toward Perforce and how things should be done better.

Comment: If you're making an integration for a game engine, focus your efforts on having it set up the client view correctly.  That always seems to be the main sticking point for game devs in practice, and the tool integrations never bother to help them with it.  :)

Comment: If you really want an atomic deletion operation, though, here's a crazy workaround: designate a "graveyard" area of the depot.  Move the file to that area (which you can do atomically while it's open for edit), submit it, and then delete it in a followup changelist.  Make your tool aware that if something has been moved to the graveyard, it counts as "deleted" and should not be "edited" by re-adding it.